# Right way to design a mobile ASP.NET MVC 4 data entry application with HTML5 offline capabilities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, offline-caching, cache-manifest

I'm creating a PoC of an ASP.NET MVC 4 mobile application (tablets) for field operators that needs to support offline capabilities. It's a relatively simple data entry application with a WebAPI backend that will use a SQL database as persistent storage.

This is the first time I'll be implementing offline support, so I'm a bit unsure of which is the best way to design this. Right now I can think of two ways, and not sure which one is better or more correct.

What I want is that whenever there is internet connectivity, the information is retrieved from the server. If the connection is lost, I want the latest information to be cached/served and available to display to the user.

Based on a few tests that I've made, the way the HTML5 offline support appears to work is that as soon as any of the Views is loaded, the browser will check the manifest and cache the version of each page at that moment of time. If my understanding is correct, that means that if the user adds new entries after the browser downloaded the manifest files, then those records would not show in the offline version.

One way I can think to work around that is to change the manifest version (since I'm generating it dynamically) every time it is served, but i feel that would defeat the purpose..or at least be incredibly inefficient bandwidth-wise.

The only other alternative that I can think of is not using regular MVC (not passing the records/db information as the model property or a ViewBag property) to display the records, but just retrieve the json for the page information needed and save in local storage. Then, generate the view using a template or javascript based on the information in localstorage. That would work either online or offline, wouldn't it?

I'm not sure if I'm approaching this the wrong way. Would building an SPA or a simple HTML/javascript application be more appropiate? Maybe using a JS framework? At this point I have some ability to determine what technology or framework we'd use.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just as additional information, here are a few things I've learned while researching how to build this app. I might be wrong. If so, please correct me, just wanted to share in case someone is just starting with this topic, like I am:

1. The natural idea/mode/paradigm behind offline functionality through cache manifests in HTML5 is that the UI (html) is completely separate and independent from the data. That is, it's not a natural fit for server side generated HTML. "Legacy" application is what they call that in http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#offline

Comment: 2. In theory, you can still fit offline functionality with those server-side html generating applications, by adding the URLs to both the CACHE and the NETWORK sections, and adding the SETTINGS section to the manifest, and specifying the prefer-online setting. However, that's completely unreliable since some browsers don't support it yet, so the setting is ignore and you're stuck with a stale version of your data.

Comment: Thanks for sharing all this info! I'm learning a lot from you on this matter. Were you able to get all this working with ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Based on a few tests that I've made, the way the HTML5 offline support appears to work is that as soon as any of the Views is loaded, the browser will check the manifest and cache the version of each page at that moment of time. If my understanding is correct, that means that if the user adds new entries after the browser downloaded the manifest files, then those records would not show in the offline version.

This is why you shouldn't use server side rendering. When the server mixes data with formatting before sending to the browser it means that the browser can't tell the difference between the two. HTML5 and Javascript are perfectly capable of handling templating on their own so why not let them?

Write your MVC application as nothing but a series of controller methods. Do not use "views" per-say. Instead use straight HTML files that use javascript to make AJAX requests to the server for data. Populate the HTML view with the data and you're golden. Then you can cache the HTML files because they're static and you can save the data separately for offline mode.

Comment: seems reasonable Spencer, and it appears to be the way to go. One question about this approach though. What would be the best pattern to use to keep the latest information available on localStorage? At this moment I am not sure about how frequently the information would be changing, but knowing about what the best pattern to sync/retrieve would be nice. Any ideas?

Comment: Off the top of my head I would create a GUID field for the table of records I am retrieving. Every time a record is updated a new GUID is generated and saved with the changes. When the browser determines it has internet access I would submit all the IDs and the GUIDs associated with them to the server. The server would then be able to pick out records that have been updated since the browser cached them. Server sends them off and the browser updates it's local storage.

Comment: I would recommend doing some googling though as I'm sure there are other concerns that need to be addressed and perhaps even some frameworks available that make the whole process a lot easier to manage.

Comment: Great, thanks Spencer. Your answer makes sense, even more after realizing that if you include a certain URL/page/view on the cache of the manifest, it apparently is served from the cache everytime, so, like you said, caching just the HTML would be ideal.

Comment: Glad to help! If you have any more questions about using HTML/JS views feel free to leave me a comment somewhere with a link. I've been using this approach for a while now so I may be able to help out.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, might take you up on your word at some point as I build this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer, there's a thorough post in this matter titled:

[Build an HTML5 Offline Application with Application Cache, Web Storage and ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1112051).

The guy explains everything using a sample/complete app and do a great job explaining each and every point.

---

Besides that, if you really want to get the [crème de la crème](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cr%C3%A8me_de_la_cr%C3%A8me) from modern web dev with offline capabilities, I'd suggest you take the 2 parts course by extraordinaire/star developer [John Papa](http://www.johnpapa.net/). It uses the [SPA = Single Page Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) UI paradigm.

The course is available at Pluralsight:

[Building Apps with Angular and Breeze - Part 1](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/build-apps-angular-breeze)

[Building Apps with Angular and Breeze - Part 2](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/build-apps-angular-breeze-part2)

Enjoy as much as I'm enjoying it. Make sure you check this keyword/feature in the course: [`WIP = Work In Progress.`](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular.breeze.storagewip)

If you're interested, here's is a repo where I keep the updated course's code:
https://github.com/leniel/SPACodeCamper